# Import options doesn't show .zmbx files

Tags: import

I am using Blender 3.1.2. I have a .zmbx file from Mecabricks that I want to import but, the import options doesn't show .zmbx files. I added the mecaface add on and it works fine on other models but I can't upload .zmbx file since there is no option to for import. I looked for it on add on but is not there. any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for ? https://www.mecabricks.com/en/shop/product/2

Comment: Gorgious is correct. Blender Lite is the addon you need in order to *import* .zmbx files.